# Python generate IEEE 754 double-precision binary floating-point format

Tags: python-3.x

I need the IEEE 754 double-precision representation of a number for a compiler project I am currently working on. I was wondering if there is a module to generate the representation or if I need to implement it myself?

Comment: Is something like: `struct.pack('d', 1.234)` which gives you: `
b'X9\xb4\xc8v\xbe\xf3?'` what you're after?

Comment: @Jon Clements is there a way to get hex dec like 3FF3BE76C8B43958 instead of b'X9\xb4\xc8v\xbe\xf3?

Comment: So is `binascii.hexlify(struct.pack('>d', 1.234))` what you're after then? (if so will probably make that an answer)

Comment: @Jon Clements This indeed gets the job done. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`struct.pack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.pack) to generate the bytes then use the `bytes.hex` method to get it as a hex string, eg:

```
import struct

# >d = big-endian byte order double
rep = struct.pack('>d', 1.234).hex()
# 3ff3be76c8b43958
```